Roof over A/C condensor awning style
Looking to put an addition and a sunporch on the back of my home and I'm looking for solutions with regards to giving the A/C condenser good airflow while still being able to roof over the area with a shed dormer style metal roof.
In the picture below the right of the red line is where i want the sun porch to go and i want to install a laundry/mud roomin the white area straight back with back entrance coming out to a covered patio where the A/C unit is.  I'd prefer to go with a dormer transition all the way across the roof for both continuity as well as to not have drainage headaches, not to mention minimizing gutter work since I would just detach and reattach the gutter on the edge of the new roof.
I'd prefer not to extend the A/C lines for both efficiency and to not incur the cost of servicing the unit after. Plan would be to enclose the sunporch and leave the area between the red line and the white addition open air with just the roof over it like an awning.
Will this adversely effect airflow? Roof would be at minimum 9-10 feet off the ground.

See if you can find the installation manual of the unit, or contact the manufacturer, to see how much clear space is required around the unit.

Can you clarify what kind of roof you mean?  Never seen a shed+dormer roof.

A shed dormer...essentially a flat dormer that spans the length of the house.  They call it a shed dormer because it doesnt have a gable and is jst a flat panel that sits at a shallower angle than the original roof, allowing it to tie in with a single drip edge transition.  Doing so would enable a simpler construction process, look better, and, like I said, allow the gutter to be directly transferred to the new roof edge

I don't think it will have any adverse effects.  It is common to have the outside units under soffits or on porches, balconies and verandahs.
If you want to be absolutely sure that look up the manuals on the unit and see what the manufacturers says for distances.  If you dont have the manuals, you can easily find them on line.
